# relode table jquery not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with surcharge as a table, I'm using this instruction to reload the table after an event ajax

```
$("#table").load(location.href + " #table");
```

Recharging works as well but for some reason, it generates the table recharge within the table and is something like

```
<table style="display: table;" id="table" class="table table-striped table-hover">
<table id="table" class="table table-striped table-hover">
```

and this seems to me that makes buttons that have actions do not work

```
<td>
<button class="btn register btn-skin-green btn-xs" data-store-code="13"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-eye"></i>Ver</button>
<button class="btn eliminar btn-skin-green btn-xs" data-store-code="13"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-eye"></i>Eliminar</button>
</td>
```

> js

```
$('.eliminar').click(function() {
        var valor = $(this).data('storeCode');
        var mes = "Mayo";
        var route = "../../ADIC/" + valor + "/eliminar";
        var token = document.getElementById('token').getAttribute('content')

        if(valor != null){

        $.ajax({
        url: route,
        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data:{id: valor},
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#resultado").html('<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>');

            },
            success: function(data){
                $("#resultado").html('');  
                $('#resultado').fadeOut(1000);

                $("#table").fadeOut(1000);
                $("#table").load(location.href + " #table");
                $("#table").fadeIn(1000);


            },
            error: function() {

            }
        });
        }else{
        }
    });
```

> view

```
  <table id="table" class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
        <th>Fecha</th>
        <th class="hidden-xs">Cancha</th>
        <th>Partido</th>
        <th>Juez - 1</th>
        <th>Juez - 2</th>
        <th>Estado</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($users as $users)
        <span id="resultado"></span>
        <tr
        @if($users->Check_J1 == 1 && $users->Check_J2 == 1 )
        class="success"
        @else
        class="danger"
        @endif
        >
            <td>{!!$users->Fecha!!}</td>
            <td class="hidden-xs">{!!$users->Cancha!!}</td>
            <td>{!!$users->EquipoA!!} vs {!!$users->EquipoB!!} ({!!$users->Categoria!!})</td>
            <td>{!!$users->Numero_J1!!} - {!!$users->Nombre_J1!!} {!!$users->Apellido_J1!!}</td>
            <td>{!!$users->Numero_J2!!} - {!!$users->Nombre_J2!!}  {!!$users->Apellido_J2!!}</td>
            <td><button class="btn register btn-skin-green btn-xs" data-store-code={!! $users->id!!} ><i class="fa fa-fw fa-eye"></i>Ver</button><button class="btn eliminar btn-skin-green btn-xs" data-store-code={!! $users->id!!} ><i class="fa fa-fw fa-eye"></i>Eliminar</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

Comment: the first works, reload the information, but the second time loading the table within the table and does not work more

Comment: can you give me an example of what the "data" looks like coming back from "success"?